# What is the max amount of characters that can be used for Okta login?

Tags: email, authentication, limit, okta

I have been searching through the technical specification of Okta and have been unable to find the max amount - I have found the following:

https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/Reference_Directories.htm

This talks about quite a bit but really doesn't answer the login attribute question - it does give quite a bit of information about email, which if we follow the RFC's and the addendums to the RFC's that number is 254 characters. Found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid1690

There, however, is additional information that seems to indicate that attributes carry no limit - which can't be the case, especially in regards to email addresses:

https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/What-is-the-maximum-allowed-size-of-an-Okta-attribute?language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has changed over the years. Currently (and just tested this in an okta.com tenant), the maximum total length the Okta login and primary email fields is 100 characters total combined (prefix and suffix).